# Bring button to front on Windows Phone UI

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, telerik

On the main page of my app I have a grid with 6 x 4 columns and rows of buttons.

I want to move one of these buttons to the middle and then scale it larger using RadControls by Telerik.

I can do this easily however when I do the button is shown behind all the other buttons on the grid and I can't seem to make it come to the front.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order that items were added to a panel/grid determines what control is above another. Looking around it looks like you have two options:

1. Change the Canvas.ZIndex for the button you want to be on top.
   Yes it seems odd as there is no canvas, but it works for any panel or grid.
2. Remove and re-add the child from the parent grid so that it was last. I found a nice snippet of code here posted by "CleverCoder" : http://forums.silverlight.net/post/63607.aspx

   ```
   //Originally posted by CleverCode - http://forums.silverlight.net/post/63607.aspx
   public static void PushToTop(this FrameworkElement element)
   {
       if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
       var parentPanel = element.Parent as Panel;
       if (parentPanel != null)
       {
           // relocate the framework element to be the last in the list (which makes it "above" everything else)
           parentPanel.Children.Remove(element);
           parentPanel.Children.Add(element);
           parentPanel.UpdateLayout();
       }
   }
   ```